# DIV из ячейки таблицы поверх других других строк таблицы

Tags: html, css, jquery, table

Есть такая таблица:

```
<table border="1" width="700px">
<tr>
  <td class='name-product' name="name-product-001">
    какой-то непонятный текст
    <div class='tooltip-product' name="tooltip-product-001">
                Что-то написано <br> в несколько <br> строк.
        </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='name-product' name="name-product-002">
    какой-то непонятный текст  
    <div class='tooltip-product' name="tooltip-product-002">
                Что-то написано <br> в несколько <br> строк.
        </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='name-product' name="name-product-003">
    какой-то непонятный текст  
    <div class='tooltip-product' name="tooltip-product-003">
                Что-то написано <br> в несколько <br> строк.
        </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Стилями и jquery div в каждой строке скрыт
Нужно, чтобы при наведении на строку div из неё появлялся поверх всей таблицы, а при наведении на div или уходе из ячейки - прятался.

Мои попытки тут: http://jsfiddle.net/bahdpv62/7/
Всё прячется и появляется, но под элементами таблицы.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Внутренний элемент с z-index, не может перекрыть внешние элементы, которые перекрывают родителя этого элемента... Надо делать один единственный блок, который будет вообще вне таблицы, с высоким z-index перекрывать всё. И наполняться контентом-показываться во время наведения.

Comment: К сожалению, такой вариант не подходит, т. к. таблица генерируется php на сервере данными из БД. Т. е. каждая строка - это отдельный товар, а во всплывающем div-е - его параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица генерируется php (с) — одно другому не мешает. Пример всплывающего описания:

```js
setTableTooltip();

function setTableTooltip() {
  var tip = createTipBlock();
  var tipWid = tip.offsetWidth;
  var limit = document.body.offsetWidth - tipWid;
  // Ширина страницы - ширина подсказки = точка, после которой блок выходит за экран.

  tip.style.display = "none";
  // Нельзя узнать offsetWidth невидимого элемента (дает 0), поэтому узнал, потом скрыл.

  var tdProduct = document.querySelectorAll('td.name-product');

  [].slice.call(tdProduct).forEach(function(td) {

    td.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
      tip.innerHTML = td.querySelector('.tooltip-product').innerHTML;
      tip.style.display = "block";
    });

    td.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      var shift = (e.pageX > limit) ? (tipWid + 20) : 0;
      // Если выходим за рамки страницы - сдвиг в размере ширины всплывающего блока.

      tip.style.left = e.pageX + 10 - shift + 'px';
      tip.style.top = e.pageY + 10 + 'px';
    });

    td.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      tip.style.display = "none";
    });

  });


  function createTipBlock() {
    var tip = document.createElement('div');
    tip.className = "tooltip";

    document.body.appendChild(tip);
    return tip;
  }
}
```

```css
.common-table { border-collapse: collapse; }
.common-table td { width: 700px; border: 1px solid #b89868; padding: 5px; }
.common-table tr:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #fff1ba; }
.common-table tr:nth-child(2n-1) { background-color: #ffe2aa; }

.name-product { cursor: pointer; }

.tooltip-product { display: none; }

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 4px solid #ffe2aa;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000, 0 0 0 1px #800, inset 0 0 0 1px #a77;
}
```

```html
<table class="common-table">
  <tr>
    <td class='name-product' name="name-product-001">
      какой-то непонятный текст
      <div class='tooltip-product' name="tooltip-product-001">
        Что-то написано<br>в несколько<br>строк 1111.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='name-product' name="name-product-002">
      какой-то непонятный текст
      <div class='tooltip-product' name="tooltip-product-002">
        Что-то написано<br>в несколько<br>строк 2222.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='name-product' name="name-product-003">
      какой-то непонятный текст
      <div class='tooltip-product' name="tooltip-product-003">
        Что-то написано<br>в несколько<br>строк 3333.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это оказалось тем решением, которое мне было нужно. Всё работает как надо.